# How to remove specific files multiple directories

Tags: apache2, mysql

ubuntu newbie and incompetent tech user here. After trying to install Nextcloud along with a ton of dependencies using [this guide](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-nextcloud-19-on-ubuntu-server-20-04/) (failed), I changed my mind and halted the process. Now I've got a bunch of useless MySQL and Apache2 files on my computer, and I'd like to clean up. I cannot delete the files in the File Manager, so I'm guessing I'll have to do so using the Terminal. Problem: No idea how to do so.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If it is permissions then using sudo in the terminal may be required, the gui will be limited to the logged in user and may be what's preventing you from making changes. You can use chown to alter the permissions of files or rm to remove them. rm has flags such as -f which be be required to brute force it. But you should not be removing files unless you are sure you don't need them. **sudo rm /file/to/delete.txt**. Anything installed using apt should be removed the same way, so **sudo apt autoremove vlc** would be preferred to manual deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not manually remove files from the operating system.

Those files you mention get removed when you `purge` the package you installed. You can use the same commands you used to install and replace `install` with `purge` (ie. `sudo apt purge mysql-server`  and that will remove anything mysql related. Including database and configs except for manually added files (like a personal `my.cnf`)). Same works for apache and nextcloud.

You could leave the dependencies if you want (those are more dangerous to delete: check the text it comes back with for packages you do not want removed if it lists them).

In case you used `remove`  to remove mysql, apache2 and it left files you could remove them but I do not like to guess what files that are. You can remove files from your admin account with `sudo rm {filename}` from command line and use * as a wildcard.

So this command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server -y
sudo apt-get install php zip libapache2-mod-php php-gd php-json php-mysql php-curl php-mbstring php-intl php-imagick php-xml php-zip php-mysql php-bcmath php-gmp
```

becomes:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get purge php zip libapache2-mod-php php-gd php-json php-mysql php-curl php-mbstring php-intl php-imagick php-xml php-zip php-mysql php-bcmath php-gmp -y
```

and try to avoid using `-y` as it will confirm every question automatically. There are occasions where you want to cancel the installation.

Again: the last command is dangerous. It removes "php" and "zip" and if you use those for anything else you do not want to remove it.

Contents of `/var/www/html/` is considered personal. If you have content in there you can do a `rm -rf /var/www/html/`. "rm" removes files so make sure this is what you want to remove. If you have more than 1 website and you want to keep those do not use this.

Comment: Thank you! I have nothing of importance in /var/www/html/, so I tried to delete it but was denied permission. Didn't even prompt me for a password, any idea why that might be?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out and probably just did what you told me not to do. I manually deleted the individual files using `sudo rm -rf /var/www/html/     sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/   sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2/`  Hope there's no backlash :D

Comment: There is likely a `/var/lib/mysql` too? In `/var/log/` there is likely a log file for mysql and apache.